# jQuery click won't work with new infinite scroll elements

Tags: jquery, onclick, infinite-scroll

On my page, I have a list with items and you can click on a "View More" button which shows you more information about this topic. This click function is in jQuery on an other page. I've implemented an infinite scroller on this page, but now the button "View More" doesn't work on the new elements, only on the first element.

FYI: I didn't code this application, my task is just to add the infinite scroll.

I've searched the web about this issue and I've read a few times this might be because the new elements aren't initialized or something. But I never found how I could solve this issue.

Here is the code of the infinite scroller:

var reachedEnd = false;

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            lastPostFunc();
    }
});

function lastPostFunc() {

    var trs = $('.sresult-row'); /*get the number of trs*/
    var count = trs.length; /*this will work as the offset*/

    /*Restricting the request if the end is reached.*/
    if (reachedEnd == false) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/jingjobs/index.php/search/ajax_searchJob/" + count,
            async: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data != "End")
                    $('.result-bd').append(data);
                else
                    reachedEnd = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code of the "View More" click function:

```
$('.click-job-viewmore').click(function(e) {

    var abtn = $(this).parents('.sresult-row').find('.job-btn-submit');
    var abtn_submitted = $(this).parents('.sresult-row').find('.job-btn-submitted');
    var requestinterviewbtn = $(this).parents('.sresult-row').find('.jobseeker_request_interview');

    var oDom = $(this).parents('.sresult-row').find('.sresult-par2');
    var aMark = $(this).parents('.sresult-row').find('.job-mark');
    var aViewMore = $(this).find('.job-viewmore');
    var aEdit = $(this).find('.job-edit');

    if (oDom.css('display') == 'none') {

        if (window.location.href.indexOf('search/searchJobseeker') > 0) {
            $.post(site_url + 'user/updateVisitNum',
                    {uid: aViewMore.attr('alt')},
            function(result) {
            });

        }

        aMark.addClass('job-mark2').removeClass('job-mark1');

        oDom.slideDown();

        abtn.css({display: 'block'}).show();
        abtn_submitted.css({display: 'block'}).show();

        requestinterviewbtn.css({display: 'block'}).show();

        aViewMore.html("View Less");
        aViewMore.css({
            'color': '#674092'
        });
    } else {
        oDom.slideUp();

        abtn.hide();
        abtn_submitted.hide();

        requestinterviewbtn.hide();

        aMark.addClass('job-mark1').removeClass('job-mark2');

        aViewMore.html("View More");
        aViewMore.css({
            'color': '#ea6e3b'
        });
    }

    e.stopPropagation();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
$(document).on("click",".click-job-viewmore",function(e) {});
```

Because you should use [delegates](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically created objects. It will help you to attach events for future elements to be created.

Comment: That's just what I needed. I already read something about delegates, but I didn't know what or how, so thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there also a way to do something similar for a jQuery .find("elementname");? Because some kind of fxuitabs are used in this page aswell which aren't working anymore.

Comment: If they are static elements, you can use find() method. But in the case of dynamic elements, there need delegates

Comment: They are also dynamic with the infinite loader. But they don't got a click function or something but they're searched by .find(). So how should I use this delegates here?

Answer (score 0):

```
Attach the click event to the document 

$(document).on('click','element' function(){});
```